# boost::interprocess sync mechanisms (mutex, condition) in shared memory between 32 & 64 bit programs on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, ipc, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

OSX 10.11.6, boost 1.63.0

I have a 64 bit **master** process that is using a 32 bit **slave** process to do some realtime rendering (I don't have the source code to a particular 32 bit dynamic library so I can't recompile it as 64 bit). Timing is critical and I've found the shared memory utilities of boost::interprocess to work very well, but I've run into interoperability issues. Some of the interprocess mechanisms are different sizes when compiled 32 vs 64 & thus cause issues when the **slave** references them from the shared memory.

```
64 bit
Scoped Lock: 16
Condition: 48
Mutex: 64
Semaphore: 4

32 bit
Scoped Lock: 8
Condition: 28
Mutex: 44
Semaphore: 4
```

I dug down into the boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex header and found the sizes declared in **_pthread_types.h**:

```
// pthread opaque structures
#if defined(__LP64__)
#define __PTHREAD_SIZE__        8176
#define __PTHREAD_ATTR_SIZE__       56
#define __PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_SIZE__  8
#define __PTHREAD_MUTEX_SIZE__      56
#define __PTHREAD_CONDATTR_SIZE__   8
#define __PTHREAD_COND_SIZE__       40
#define __PTHREAD_ONCE_SIZE__       8
#define __PTHREAD_RWLOCK_SIZE__     192
#define __PTHREAD_RWLOCKATTR_SIZE__ 16
#else // !__LP64__
#define __PTHREAD_SIZE__        4088
#define __PTHREAD_ATTR_SIZE__       36
#define __PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_SIZE__  8
#define __PTHREAD_MUTEX_SIZE__      40
#define __PTHREAD_CONDATTR_SIZE__   4
#define __PTHREAD_COND_SIZE__       24
#define __PTHREAD_ONCE_SIZE__       4
#define __PTHREAD_RWLOCK_SIZE__     124
#define __PTHREAD_RWLOCKATTR_SIZE__ 12
#endif // !__LP64__

struct _opaque_pthread_mutex_t {
    long __sig;
    char __opaque[__PTHREAD_MUTEX_SIZE__];
};
```

When using

```
boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex
boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition
```

with both programs compiled as 64 bit, the data rendering works extremely well.

Is there any way to force size conformity? Or perhaps there's a different IPC mechanism I'm overlooking?

The great thing about using conditions is that they can signal the blocked thread when to wake and greatly minimize wasted CPU cycles, since the waiting thread/process doesn't have to be constantly running to check a value. Is there another way to signal threads/processes in this manner?

I know of at least a couple programs on OSX that have implemented highly fast and efficient data rendering between 64 bit <-> 32 bit so the answer's gotta be out there somewhere..

Comment: You've probably already checked this but just to make sure: Have you verified that other ipc mechanisms are too slow for you?

Comment: I've used boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore since they only consists of an atomic uint32, but the issue there is that both threads will waste a lot of cycles spin-waiting for the value to go down. I've tried calibrating sleep times but even then I've gotten either data dropouts//overloads or too much unused CPU usage. I was just assuming synching over pipe or sockets would be too slow but mine as well give it a whirl!

Comment: Yes, Pipes, domain sockets and or fifos was what I thought about. They are certainly much slower than shared memory, so they might not work for you, but they provide a fairly strong decupling between the different applications. Depending on what you do with the data it might be good enough. Sadly I've very little experience in that field so I wouldn't be surprised if there is a simple solution I just don't know about. Maybe you could reverse engineer the boost types and create your own portable version.

Answer (score 2):

So I took the advice of MikeMB & did some research on pipes. I found this paper http://ace.ucv.ro/sintes12/SINTES12_2005/SOFTWARE%20ENGINEERING/44.pdf which suggests using pipes as a locking mechanism. It looks like reading/writing to a pipe implements the same signaling mechanisms of an interprocess condition variable so the thread blocking/waking is quite efficient.

And it looks like the reading/writing is fast enough for my realtime setup on my machine! (def can't guarantee it'll work on other machines yet though, I've only tested on my 2011 MBP (2.2 GHz Intel Core i7))

It seems to work as well as conditions, and I haven't gotten any data dropouts yet. Here's what I made. Just place one of these in shared memory and the **master** and **slave** processes can call wait() & post() accordingly.

```
struct PipeSemaphore
{
    PipeSemaphore()
    {
        // make sure semaphore will work in shared memory
        // between 32 <-> 64 bit processes
        static_assert (sizeof (int) == 4);

        int res = pipe (p);

        // pipe failed to open
        if (res == -1)
            assert (false);
    }

    ~PipeSemaphore()
    {
        close (p[0]);
        close (p[1]);
    }

    // if nothing is in the pipe stream,
    // the curr thread will block
    inline int wait() noexcept
    {
        char b;
        return read (p[0], &b, 1);
    }

    // writing to the pipe stream will notify
    // & wake blocked threads
    inline int post() noexcept
    {
        return write (p[1], "1", 1);
    }

private:
    int p[2];
};
```

Any suggestions to the code would be greatly appreciated!